# Bonding in a soldering station

Tags: soldering

I have a soldering station which came with a 3.5mm jack socket and a power prong as in the following photo:

[image]

The manual only mentions the following about the usage for the 3.5mm jack in their manual as:

[image]

What is the need for this? I never saw this in previous stations. Does anybody have experience with such wiring? Which one is safe in my case? Do I really have to earth this?
I couldn't find any information in the manual.

Comment: Make, model & link to datasheet / user manual? It is hard to visualise where the jack plug is supposed to go.

Comment: People have various needs/requirements on how to do the grounding, this product tries to give options.

Comment: @Transistor They only have a very short page in net http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/soldering-stations/7989339/ In their video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mOsZDQU2qPw they use that bonding. But it is annoying to try to hook it up to earth each time if you use it mobile. I will probably ignore it.

Answer (score 5):

> What is the need for this?

To expand on the comment from *PlasmaHH*, that soldering station (and several other Weller products) give you options about the earthing of the soldering iron tip.

There is a specific socket on the soldering station, where that jack plug (and any connections to it - see below) is inserted.

> I never saw this in previous stations.

I have seen several soldering stations that provide a separate terminal for connecting the iron tip to a local ground. This use of a jack plug just offers more options (explained below).

Some soldering stations from another brand only use the mains earth connection to ground the tip (no other options). They monitor that mains earth connection and shut down the soldering station of that mains earth connection is broken.

There are probably other approaches by different manufacturers too.

> Do I really have to earth this?

You *usually* don't want the tip of a soldering iron to be "floating".

By default, using that Weller 81i soldering station, the soldering iron tip is connected to the earth pin in your mains cable:

[image: Weller WSD81i manual - default bonding state of soldering iron tip]

That point in the manual is saying, *without* the jack plug inserted, the soldering iron tip is "hard grounded" i.e. it is *directly connected* to the soldering station's mains earth connection.

Therefore the question you need to ask yourself is: Is the earth pin in your mains power socket, connected to a low impedance local earth? If so, then the soldering station will behave like typical mains-powered irons, with the tip connected to the mains earth, when that 3.5mm plug is not inserted (i.e. the "as delivered" state).

> Which one is safe in my case?

You have not explained "your case" and what exactly you need. However there are only a few choices. Here is a slightly different version than the one you kindly provided, of the relevant extract from the manual:

[image: Weller WSD81i manual - tip bonding options]

---

Going down the list in that image and using the same reference letters:

- (a) Hard-grounded

  This is the "as delivered" state, with the jack plug not inserted.

  The soldering iron tip is directly connected to the earth pin of the mains input socket of the soldering station. If you want the tip to be earthed, then you are responsible for ensuring that the mains earth connection to the soldering station is good enough and suitable for that purpose. Some examples of things which could go wrong, would be if you have a disconnected mains earth connection, or where your mains earth and neutral are swapped.
- (b) Equipotential bonding

  This is when you connect a wire to the centre contact of the jack plug.

  Now the soldering iron tip is connected only to whatever is at the other end of that wire, and *not* to mains earth. This connection via the wire could be a local earth, to perform equipotential bonding between multiple parts of an ESD setup, where the mains earth connection is not suitable for any reason.
- (c) Floating

  This is when the jack plug is inserted, but with absolutely *no* connections to it.

  Again, the soldering iron tip is connected to the centre pin of the jack plug (like in option (b) above) but in this case, there is absolutely *nothing* connected there, so the tip is floating. This would usually be banned by an ESD policy. At the moment I can only think of one, unusual, use for doing this.
- (d) Soft-grounded

  This is when the jack plug is inserted, with a resistor (e.g. 1MΩ shown in the picture) between its centre and outer pins.

  This is a variation of option (a) - the soldering iron tip is connected to the earth pin of the mains input socket of the soldering station *via that resistor*. Again this relies on the mains earth connection to the soldering station being "good enough".

  Using "soft-grounding" (and choosing the value of that resistor) is a compromise between keeping the soldering iron tip *firmly* at the same voltage (i.e. ground) as other parts on your ESD bench (needs low resistance to ground), and reducing possible damage to a charged *device*, by it discharging via the soldering iron tip (needs higher resistance to ground).

> I couldn't find any information in the manual.

This is probably because the option you select depends on your company's local ESD policy, which the soldering station manufacturer doesn't decide. The default option (soldering iron tip "hard connected" to mains earth input) is a common standard - but not the only one. That is why having choices can be useful. If you have questions, check the ESD policy of your organisation regarding soldering iron tip earthing.

In an "amateur" situation where your ESD procedures may be incomplete, leading to some devices remaining charged before soldering, then I suggest the "soft-grounding" option with a 1MΩ resistor (with a confirmed "good" earth connection to the soldering station) should be considered.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. If I use hard-grounded config. I need a 3 prong AC plug then right?(Since they sent 2 prong plug as you see in the photo.) And what could be an issue with floating iron tip if I use floating option?

Comment: You're welcome :-) "*I need a 3 prong AC plug then right?*" Unless you're using the unusual equipotential option (option (b) in the list), then yes. "*they sent 2 prong plug as you see in the photo*" That plug has 3 (actually 4) connections - 2 power pins + earth connection via the top round hole or top "slot", or via the bottom slot. See types E & F [here](http://www.worldstandards.eu/electricity/plugs-and-sockets/). The earth connection is via a pin on socket type E or a "tab" on socket type F. Don't use in an ungrounded type C socket. Floating tips can accumulate a static charge = ESD risk.